# c++ app crashing on non AVX CPUs

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, avx

I have an AVX optimized app which I do not need to make compatible with non AVX CPUs. However, I would like to display a clean error dialog on these older CPUs, rather than having the app crashing, as that causes customer confusion.

In my `main()` I create the `QApplication` instance (I'm using the Qt framework), then test for AVX using gcc `__builtin_cpu_supports ("avx")`. If it fails, I display an error dialog. This proved to work on non-AVX CPUs on a simple test app.

However, our (large) application crashes before displaying the dialog box on non AVX CPUs.

I have suspected:

- Global variable initialization somewhere which uses AVX intrinsics. I'm not 100% sure to have checked everywhere, but it seems this is not the case.
- gcc optimizer uses AVX instructions on some code called before the check.

Problem is, I have no non-AVX system at work for debugging and I would prefer avoiding purchasing one if possible.

1. Is it possible to disable AVX when debugging on my CPU so that debugger stops on any AVX instruction?
2. Any alternative ideas?

Comment: Why not run `simple test app` always and if all ok, then `simple test app` will run `main complex app`?

Comment: Already discussed in [this forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/508413). [Intel Software Development Emulator](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-software-development-emulator) suggested.

Comment: Do you receive a `SIGILL`, and could you install a handler for that?

Comment: @Toby : I do not know, how can I do this? Using mingw gcc.

Comment: Run your app under gdb or whatever other debugger on a non-avx CPU, and see where it dies.  Do a backtrace to see how you got where you are.  Both your guesses are good, it could be either.

Comment: Note that when gcc compiles `static const __m256i myconstant = _mm256_set...(...)`, you actually get code to dynamically initialize constants.  It's really dumb that it can't just compile it to static data, but it doesn't.  You get better result from using local `const __m256i myconstant = ...` in every function that needs it.  gcc and clang will both merge identical constants from separate functions into a single read-only constant, the same way they merge identical string literals.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a (non-optimised) wrapper program that performs the feature test, then either exits with a friendly message or execs your application.

The `QApplication` constructor is allowed to modify the passed arguments, so you'll need to take a copy (or not use any Qt in the path that goes through to `exec()`).

Something like (from my head):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (__builtin_cpu_supports ("avx")) {
        execv("/the/real/program", argv);
        perror("exec");
        exit 1;
    } else {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        QDialog d;
        d.show();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

VMWare can [fake the CPUID](http://vknowledge.net/2014/04/17/how-to-fake-a-vms-guest-os-cpuid/) of the guest OS, and you could just turn off all AVX bits.

However, this is just lying to the application : it won't cause the app to break into the debugger if it still executes that AVX instruction.

Comment: That does not solve my issue! I cannot find where the faulty AVX instruction is hidden

Comment: @galinette This actually will solve your problem. The AVX instructions need to be enabled by the OS before they can be used. If the OS doesn't detect that the CPU supports AVX instructions it won't enable them.

Comment: This will disable AVX detection, but the AVX instructions will still run fine, if I'm right.

Comment: This should be testable with a small program.  I don't know enough about this specific case, but in general, architectural changes that add more user-accessible registers need to be explicitly enabled by whatever OS you're using: you mustn't expose the registers to applications unless you know they will be preserved across context switches.  Certainly worth a try.  OTOH, if AVX merely provides new instructions rather than additional registers, your chance of success is less likely.

Comment: @TobySpeight: That's not how things work, there's no x64 instruction to "expose registers". And without hardware support, it would be far to slow to fake such "exposing" in the OS. Besides, what would be gained? A program that _doesn't_ use the extra registers isn't affected at all. A program that _does_ use the extra registers isn't affected either; it still won't run. A program that_conditionally_ uses the extra registers must check CPUID and not be affected either. The real edge case here is a program which uses AVX registers, doesn't check for them, and wants a customized error.